# How to hide asp.net mvc3.0 webgrid column dynamically?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, dynamic, hide, webgrid

I have used a ASP.NET MVC 3.0 web grid to display the following data:

```
Account ID
Account Name
AccountCode
Enabled : Yes or No
```

Based on the **"Enabled"** , I need to change the color of the row.
I dont need to display that column to the user. 
Though This column should not be displayed to the user, I need to add this column as i need to change the color depending on whether the value is Yes or No.

Please suggest me how to hide it from user, after changing the color of the row.